# Javascript: how do I access a key in a dynamically-named nested object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

Here's my situation: I'm working with an array that has a bunch of nested objects. One of those nested objects has a name that changes dynamically. How can I consistently access a key of one of it's child objects?

Here's a few examples of the paths that it can have:

```
kml[id].overlayData._layers.136._bounds._northEast.lat
kml[id].overlayData._layers.143._bounds._northEast.lat
kml[id].overlayData._layers.82._bounds._northEast.lat
kml[id].overlayData._layers.87._bounds._northEast.lat
kml[id].overlayData._layers.76._bounds._northEast.lat
```

The child object that I'm trying to access is 'lat', which has a couple of keys within it.

Apologies for any weird / incorrect use of terminology, I'm still trying to get my head around concepts like this.

Comment: what part is changing?

Comment: Do you know what the number of the object you want to access is? Where is that stored?

Comment: @NinaScholz The number in-between '_layers' and '_bounds'.

Comment: @Feathercrown I've edited the question to try and clarify a bit more .

Comment: is there only one property or more than one unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the key with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```
var keys = Object.keys(kml[id].overlayData._layers);

// access
keys.forEach(function (key) {
    // kml[id].overlayData._layers[key]._bounds._northEast.lat
});
```

For only one unknown key, you could use directly the first element of the keys array

```
var key = Object.keys(kml[id].overlayData._layers)[0];

// access with
kml[id].overlayData._layers[key]._bounds._northEast.lat
```

Comment: This only gets the first key; additionally, it can be a different key every time!

Comment: i do not understand you. the question was, how to access a property without knowing the name. in your answer, you know the name, but that is not the question, as i read it. please add a less complicated solution.

Comment: Our answers are both correct and flawed for different interpretations of the question.

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz, you gave the best answer to my admittedly poorly worded question! However, am I right in thinking that Object.keys won't return keys that have been marked as 'enumerable: false'?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if I understand the question correctly:

```
var number = 354; //whatever number you want to get the value from
kml[id].overlayData._layers['number']._bounds._northEast.lat
```

Note that you can't use `blahblah.123` to access a number-started property; use `blahblah['123']` instead. This also allows you to pass in variables, like the example above.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop thanks to for..in loop

```
for (var prop in kml[id].overlayData._layers) 
   console.log(kml[id].overlayData._layers[prop]._bounds._northEast.lat);
```